# Android: Unicode App title (label) not rendering

Tags: android, unicode-string

I am trying to setup the application label of a android app in Hindi (प्रयोग).

As per the Android manifest documentation the string values should be set in the unicode format, please refer to the topic: `String values` in the documentation
 (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)

However, even after setting the string value to the unicode format:

```
android:label="\\u092a\\u094d\\u0930\\u092f\\u094b\\u0917"
```

it still gets displayed as

```
\u092a\u094d\u0930\u092f\u094b\u0917
```

and not as `प्रयोग`

What could I be missing here?

Comment: can you try putting it in strings.xml files and referencing it from there?

Comment: Yes @RahulKumar Tried that too but with same results.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#label

Comment: this means they might not be parsing this value (not sure). So you can use the `प्रयोग` in the strings.xml and make it `android:translatable=false`. This will work.

Comment: @RahulKumar it doesn't seem to work with translatable=false too. 

<resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">प्रयोग</string>
</resources>

Comment: working on my machine.